# Looking to make a function that goes into the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that for some real $\alpha>0$:

$\sum_{k=1}^n{(x_k-\alpha f_k(x))^2} \leq 1$; for any $x$ in the n-dim unit ball.

Here each $f_k$ is bounded continuous map from the n-dimensional unit ball to the real numbers and $x_k$ is the $k$th coordinate of $x$.  I'm also given this bound for the middle term when I expand the equation above:

$-\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)}\leq B||x||^2$.

My problem is trying to bound the first term when I expand because I get this:

$\sum_{k=1}^n{(x_k-\alpha f_k(x))^2} = $

$\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k^2}+2\alpha(-\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)})+\alpha^2\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)^2$

I can't wrap my head around how I could bound the first term given that there's no alpha next to it.  I think I'm missing something here that's about to bite me in the face.  So help!

Comment: Is there some detail being left out? The statement is satisfied for all $x$ in the unit ball by taking $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Yup of course thanks.  $\alpha > 0$. Otherwise I won't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n=2$,  $B>0$ and put
$$f(x):=B|x|(0,1)\ .$$
Then $$-x\cdot f(x)=-(x_1,x_2)\cdot(0,1)\ B|x|\leq B|x|^2\ .$$
On the other hand
$$|(1,0)-\alpha f(1,0)|^2=1+\alpha^2B^2>1$$
for all $\alpha>0$.

Comment: That f(x) fails to satisfy $-\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)}\leq B||x||^2$ => $\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)}\geq B||x||^2>0$.  Since for x = (0,-1), you get $\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)} = -1$

Comment: For $x_2<0$, $xf = x_2f_2 < 0$ and so fails to satisfy the assumption.  But yes I only know this because I tried to find counterexamples in n=2 too. Then I realized the assumption somehow prevents me from producing vectors that are tangent or pointing into the unit circle.

Comment: @user100928: My example is alright.

Comment: It's not, it fails to satisfy the assumption when $x_2<0.$ Squares are smaller in the unit ball. And the negative sign doesn't necessarily mean the whole term is negative.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the original assumption is that $\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)}\geq B||x||^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

$\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k^2}+2\alpha(-\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)})+\alpha^2\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)^2$

$\leq \dfrac{1}{B}\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)}+2\alpha(-\sum_{k=1}^n{x_kf_k(x)})+\alpha^2\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)^2$

$\leq (\dfrac{1}{B}+2\alpha)\sum_{k=1}^n{|x_kf_k(x)|}+\alpha^2\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)^2$